# C# Constructor Chaining Clarification

Tags: c#, constructor

I have this C# code:

```
public ExpenseReportPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

// Custom constructor to pass expense report data
public ExpenseReportPage(object data) : this()
{
    // Bind to expense report data
    this.DataContext = data;
}
```

What exactly happens when I call the constructor with an object passed? I can't seem to get a grasp on the chain of events. If you were to pass an object, it would call the other constructor as well regardless?

Say you have three constructors, two of them with `this()`. Would calling either of those call the constructor without `this()`? Am I missing something?  From what I understand it is just constructor overloading that emphasizes DRY.

Essentially, it always calls the default?

Just some verification/correction in my thinking would be of huge assistance.

Thanks

EDIT:

How does it call the constructor if there is no lName (3rd arg) to pass?

```
class Student {
    string _studentType = "";
    string _id = "";
    string _fName = "";
    string _lName = "";

    public Student(string id)
        : this(id, "", "") {

    }

    public Student(string id, string fName)
        : this(id, fName, "") {

    }

    public Student(string id, string fName, string lName) {
        //Validate logic.....
        _studentType = "<student_type>";

        _id = id;
        _fName = fName;
        _lName = lName;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I now understand the defaults and it makes a lot more sense.  My question was how it could call a constructor if it did not have all the arguments.

Comment: When you call `ExpenseReportPage(someContext)`, the first thing that is invoked is the body of your empty constructor. Then your parameterfull constructor's body is called and you store `data` in the `DataContext` property.

Comment: So it would call the empty one and then the one with the data parameter?   If the empty one was not empty, what would it do?  What if the  now empty constructor took arguments that the other didn't?  (Assuming they are initialized elsewhere)

Comment: It wouldn't matter if the empty one was empty or non empty or whatever. Chained constructors are always called before the body of the constructor that is chaining to them.

Comment: What does 'How does it call the constructor if there is no lName (3rd arg) to pass?' mean?  What is 'it'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this()` is called before the constructor that chains executes. Then the chaining constructor would be called.

A common kind of example constructor chaining involves providing sensible defaults, like this:

```
class SomeData
{
    private string _string;
    private int _int; 

    public SomeData() : this("Default", 42)
    {

    }

    public SomeData(string str) : this(str, 42)
    {

    }

    public SomeData(string str, int num)
    {
        _int = num;
        _string = str; 
    }
}
```

This would allow the user of `SomeData` to instantiate it with any of the constructors.

Arguably, with optional parameters, this is better solved with:

```
public SomeData(string str = "Default", int num = 42) { }
```

With the chained constructors of `SomeData`, if I called `SomeData()`, `SomeData(string, num)` is called first. After returning, the `SomeData` parameterless constructor has access to the modifications made by the chained constructor.

Comment: What happens to the parameters str and num If you call SomeData()?  They are never passed so how does it call SomeData(string str, in num)?

Comment: Yes they are - the chained call of `: this("Default", 42)` does so.

Comment: Oh that makes sense.  So even though SomeData(string str) is never called, the default still applies?  Oh nevermind I see, each one sets defaults.

Comment: That's correct, because it's the default specified by the implementer of `SomeData`

Answer (score 2):

> What exactly happens when I call the constructor with an object passed?

The chain of execution would first call `this()` which is your parameterless constructor. Once finished, it would execute the constructor taking the `object` overload.

> If you were to pass an object, it would call the other constructor as well regardless?

Yes, because you instructed it to do so using `: this()`

> Say you have three constructors, two of them with this(). Would calling either of those call the constructor without this()?

Only if you state so explicitly. The two constructors using `this` would, the third without wouldn't.

Comment: What if the currently parameterless constructor actually took two arguments, one that the other didn't,  assuming it was initialized elsewhere?  See my edit for example.

Comment: If it took two arguments, it wouldn't be parameterless. I'm not sure i understand your question.

Comment: Great answer thank you.  Sorry, I reworded, meant the currently parameterless one.  The second example illustrates my question better.  How does it call the constructor if there is no lName to pass?

Comment: @shenk It is still unclear what you mean by this. What does "if there is no `lName` to pass" mean? Do you mean you only pass in two arguments? In that case you end up calling the second constructor (which chains to the third and passes an empty string for `lName`). If you mean something else, please clarify this.

Comment: I was confused about defaults.  I got it now.